# How to move a skewed div

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to move a skewed div from top left off screen, through the screen, to bottom right off screen.  The effect I am trying to get is that it looks like a parallelogram appears from somewhere up and to the left, and it slowly moves through the screen in a downwards and rightwards motion and then off the screen to the bottom.

Right now I have this index.html:

```
<html>                                                                          
  <head>                                                                        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />                                  
  </head>                                                                       
  <body>                                                                        
    <div class="div1" id="one"></div>                                           
  </body>                                                                                                           
</html>
```

And here is my index.css:

```
div {
  animation: rotate-all 2s 0 infinite linear alternate;
}

.div1 {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 1000px;
  transform: skew(20deg);
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  animation-name: down;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite ;

}

#one {
  top: 150px;
}

@keyframes down {
  0%  {
    transform: translate(-200px, -1000px);
    transform: skew(20deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(250px, 750px);
  }
}
```

I have two problems:

First, it is changing shape from the skewed shape (looks like a "\") to a unskewed one (looks like a "|").  If I try to add a skew in my 100% keyframe, then it does not move any more, it just stays in the same place.  I tried both orders skew then translate / translate then skew.

Second, it does not seem to start above the screen, but right in the middle of the screen.

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were overwriting the `transform` property. Transform accepts multiple styles, separated by spaces. If you add the `transform` property twice, it will overwrite the first one. Just put the `translate` and `skew` on the same line both times and it will work.

For the second part, `translate` it by percents (relative to itself) rather than pixels (absolute measures).

```css
div {
  animation: rotate-all 2s 0 infinite linear alternate;
}

.div1 {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 1000px;
  transform: skew(20deg);
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  animation-name: down;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite ;

}

#one {
  top: 150px;
}

@keyframes down {
  0%  {
    transform: translate(-200%, -200%) skew(20deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(250px, 750px) skew(20deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="div1" id="one"></div>
```